# Best webserver for windows

Tags: windows, web-server

I have a windows box (I have no choice but to run windows) and I need to host my website. I only need PHP and MySQL.

Its very important that it is:

- Very secure (I am hated by many)
- Fast
- Easy

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Built in IIS.  Make sure the OS is updated with security patches.  Running a third party web server on Windows just introduces more attack area to worry about and IIS is fast enough depending on the hardware.